# Нужно ли заключать в кавычки мысленный (только представляемый) звук?

Tags: кавычки, части-речи, оформление-текста, редактура

Скажите, пожалуйста, если персонаж книжки мысленно представляет звук, следует ли этот звук оформлять как мысль, в кавычках, или оставить как обычное звукоподражание, без? А если этот звук поставить в конце предложения, это повлияет на постановку кавычек?

1. *Этот звук он представил явственно: (")кряк-брямс(").*
2. *(")Кряк-брямс(")(,) — явственно представил он этот звук.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (09.01.2023)**

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310233)):

> В обоих случаях кавычки кажутся лишними.

*Этот звук он представил явственно: кряк-брямс.*

*Кряк-брямс — явственно представил он этот звук.*

Comment: Я несказанно рада, что "Грамота" подтвердила мои *изыскания*. Без примеров, правда, и без каких-либо объяснений... Им, авторитетам, — можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Считаю, что в таком контексте, когда что-то неодушевленное якобы издает звук и "слова говорения" отсутствуют, можно обойтись без кавычек — и в первом, и во втором предложении. Тем более что представляемое кряканье-бряканье на письме отделено соответствующими знаками.
*Этот звук он представил явственно: кряк-брямс.

Кряк-брямс — явственно представил он этот звук.*

Вот как звуки войны описывает Григорий Бакланов в книге "Пядь земли":

> Над головой у нас гудение самолетов и пулеметные очереди: др-р-р! др-р-р!
> Ж-ж-ж! — как жук, рикошетит надо мной расплющенная пуля.
> Несколько мин разрывается внизу одна за другой: ви-и-у... бах! Ви-и-и-у... — еще воет над головой, а внизу уже рвется: трах! трах! трах!..

Вот еще примеры (с кавычками и без):
*…Время пыхтело. Маховик — вжик, шестеренки — ширк, поршень — пых. Все куда-то катилось* (Игорь Вирабов. Андрей Вознесенский).
*"Вжик-вжик-вжик!" — **наговаривают** мои ботинки* (Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон).

Comment: @shampar После правки: с заменой точки на двоеточие я еще могу согласиться, а вот с пробелом после многоточия (в начале предложения) — никак! Вот примеры из справочника Розенталя: *Л. Н. Толстой писал: «…в искусстве простота, краткость и ясность есть высшее совершенство формы искусства; …А теперь вернёмся к началу этой истории, продолжавшейся двадцать лет.* Вот правила: https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/

Comment: «… И снова наступил сентябрь. Всё было у нас как в прежние годы». Если цитата приводится не полностью, то на месте пропуска (в начале, середине или конце цитаты) ставится многоточие. При этом первое слово цитаты в начале предложения пишется **с прописной буквы, даже если в источнике оно начинается со строчной буквы**. Например: «... Тяжелы ступени чужого крыльца», – говорит Данте. 
 Перед прописной всё-таки должен быть пробел, хотя... я бы не делал разницы. 
Источник: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/mnogotochie-znak-prepinaniya.html

Comment: Вот авторское предложение в начале абзаца: ***…Время пыхтело.*** Здесь нет никаких пропусков цитат и никаких пробелов. (https://litlife.club/books/273280/read?page=168) Вот еще: *…Проснулся задремавший было критик. // …Горькие строчки — но ведь «юнец из Севастополя» надежду оставлял…*

Comment: Вопрос № 235848 Если предложение начинается с многоточия, нужен ли пробел между этим многоточием и первым словом в предложении? 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка.
    Пробел не нужен. Многоточие в начале фразы пишется слитно с последующим словом.

Comment: Ну... Не нужен! А Вы изобразили пробел.

Comment: Как-то изобразил, хотя не знаю его изображения. И двоеточие.