Оформление звукоподражаний

Тук-тук, тук-тук! — громко стучало ее сердце.
Кап! — слеза упала на его щеку.
«Неужели я никогда больше его не увижу?»

Первые два предложения, по сути, оформлены как прямая речь, только без кавычек. Уместно ли такое оформление, урегулировано ли оно где-то в правилах?
В Нацкорпусе встречаются варианты с кавычками:

«Тук-тук, тук-тук…» — стучала его трость за спиной Коркина.


«Тук-тук!» — монотонно застучало в висках.

Но есть и такие варианты:

Я вздрогнул. Тук-тук! Тук-тук! — послышалось сверху.


Тук-тук! — стучало где-то за голубыми вершинами в облаках.

Можно ли вообще такие случаи рассматривать как прямую речь? Розенталь пишет (§ 47, п. 3), что в качестве таковой может выступать звук, например эхо. Однако — вынес это в пример — после второго предложения со звукоподражанием сразу следует прямая речь человека: не стоит ли разделить уровни субъектности говорящего и сердца/капли?
Дополнительный момент: если первый пример («Тук-тук…») — классическая прямая речь по структуре, то во втором («Кап!..») нет глагола говорения и «слова автора» должны оформляться по модели вот этого примера из Розенталя (прим. 2):

— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

В соответствии с этим правилом получается:
Кап! — Слеза упала на его щеку.

Вот здесь тоже имеется информация об оформлении звукоподражаний. Нужно ли заключать в кавычки мысленный (только представляемый) звук? (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472265/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba/472270#472270)

Из статьи:  Звукоподражания как часть речи в современном русском языке

Звукоподражания – это неполнознаменательная часть речи, служащая для подражания (имитации) звуков живой и неживой природы и создающая представление о процессах, признаках и предметах реального мира. Например: Зазвонил огромный звон: бом-бом, бом-бом! Зазвонил поменьше звон: бим-бом, бим-бом! Зазвонил звонок: дзинъ... дзинь... дзинъ...! И звоночки зазвонили: дили-дили, дили-дили! (П. Ершов)

Звукоподражания выполняют в тексте следующие функции:



являются самостоятельными высказываниями и могут быть опущены без ущерба для содержания текста: Бац-бац! Раздались выстрелы (Л. Толстой); Летают уездные мухи – джж, джж! (М. Горький);

принимает участие в образовании предложения с прямой речью, выступая в качестве аналога прямой речи: Так-так, так-так! – торопливо стучали над головой ходики (К. Паустовский);



Это аналог прямой речи без кавычек: Тук-тук, тук-тук! — громко стучало ее сердце. Кап! — слеза упала на его щеку.

Кавычки не нужны:
№ 310233
Пожалуйста, ответьте, сроки поджимают! Если персонаж 
книжки мысленно представляет звук, следует ли этот звук 
оформлять как мысль, в кавычках, или оставить как обычное 
звукоподражание, без? А если этот звук поставить в конце 
предложения, это повлияет на постановку кавычек? 1. Этот 
звук он представил явственно: (")кряк-брямс("). 2. 
(")Кряк-брямс(")(,) — явственно представил он этот звук.



Ответ
В обоих случаях кавычки кажутся лишними. Этот звук он представил явственно: кряк-брямс. Кряк-брямс — явственно представил он этот звук.

«Тук-тук, тук-тук…» — стучала его трость за спиной Коркина. Как исключение, вероятно (олицетворение неживого предмета).


Почему тогда не стоит оформить: «Кап! — Слеза упала на его щеку», с прописной буквы после тире? Играет роль параллелизм с предыдущим предложением, или не то правило, или что-то другое?

Правильно: Кап! — слеза упала на его щеку.   Атрибуция (приписывание) во второй части   – это слова автора, поясняющие реплики персонажей. Но в данном случае слова автора поясняют происхождение звуков – стучит сердце, слеза капает (так они "говорят"). Поэтому здесь именно атрибуция, которая оформляется по обычным правилам.
